# Can't drag scene object onto public UnityEvent

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script with a public UnityEvent and I am trying to drag a scene object to the object slot so I can access its methods but its not accepting the object. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

The scene object is a prefab instance and I did try unpacking the prefab but it didnt make a difference.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a bit more context, like: is the script in the same scene as the prefab? Are you using UnityEvent<>?

Comment: apologies, they are in the same scene, im using  public UnityEvent onExitEvent;  which creates the little box in the inspector where you can drag in an object to access its methods (where you select Runtime or Editor and Runtime) here is a link to the inspector image if it helps  https://ibin.co/4lgDRb7vL7kJ.png

Comment: That sounds like the right way to do it. If you add a simple GameObject public field to your script can you attach your object to it?

Comment: Oh weird, no its not allowing that either. Is it maybe because the script with the public UnityEvent is a StateMachineBehavior and not a monobehavior and the object im trying to bring in has a monobehavior script? Seems like if it wouldnt allow it though it wouldnt let me create the variables.

Comment: Oh, the AnimatorContoller is not part of the scene. That must be the reason you can't attach an object from the scene. I don't have a solution off the top of my head, but I'll give it a look.

Comment: This suggestion from Unity Answers seems like one of the few available solutions. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1440091/getting-a-reference-to-an-object-from-a-state-beha.html or this https://answers.unity.com/questions/998692/cant-assign-active-gameobjects-to-public-variables.html

Comment: Hey thank you so much that was perfect, i can just access it through the animator component. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you mentioned the script you are talking about is a `StateMachineBehaviour`.

[`StateMachineBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html) does not inherit from `MonoBehaviour` but rather from [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html)

`ScriptableObject` instances "live" in the Assets not a certain Scene

You (usually) can not have any Scene references in any assets like Prefabs or ScriptableObjects.

---

There are some workarounds however that still allow you to do that. You can e.g. create `ScriptableObject` containers for every value you want to pass. Something like e.g.

```c#
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class GameObjectReference : ScriptableObject
{
    public GameObject gameObject;

    public void SetActive(bool value)
    {
        if(gameObject) gameObject.SetActive(value);
    }
}
```

such an instance of `GameObjectReference` now is a `ScriptableObject` and thus also "lives" in the Assets => you can reference it in any other asset as Prefabs and other `ScriptableObject`s.

So all you need to do is make sure that you set this value from within your scene e.g. using

```c#
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class GameObjectReferenceSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObjectReference gameObjectReferenceAsset;

    private void Awake()
    {
        gameObjectReferenceAsset.gameObject = gameObject;
    }
}
```

You can create such a reference-asset and setter pair for each type you need and transpass the required public methods so you can call them from the `UnityEvent`.

Having the `[ExecuteInEditMode]` this should also be set already in EditMode. However since "officially" it is still not possible to have a scene reference on a ScriptableObject field the value usually says `Type missmatch` but references the correct object as you should see when you click on the field.

---

Another alternative is using some kind of dependency-injection (for Unity an often mentioned and free solution is e.g. [Zenject](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/zenject-dependency-injection-ioc-17758)). It is a bit complex to set it up the first time but once you got it working it is more flexible and better scaleable since you wouldn't need to implement a wrapper for each type you want to pass in to a `StateMachineBehaviour`.

More information and how-tos about Zenject can be found on their [github page](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject)